# $\operatorname{cov}\left(\int_0^tf(s,T_1)\,dW(s,T_1),\int_0^tf(s,T_2)\,dW(s,T_1)\right)=\text{?}$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

Define a random field $W$ so that:

- $W(t,T)$ is a standard Brownian motion for every $T$.
- $dW(t,T_1) \, dW(t,T_2)=c(t,T_1,T_2)\,dt$
- $W(t,\cdot)$ is a a continuous function for every $t$.

Suppose $f$ is a deterministic function. I want to find the covariance $$ \operatorname{cov}\left(\int_0^t f(s,T_1) \, dW(s,T_1), \int_0^tf(s,T_2) \, dW(s,T_1)\right). $$

When $W$ is a BM instead of a random field, we can use $XY=\frac{1}{4}[(X+Y)^2-(X-Y)^2]$ to find the covariance but I don't think it is possible in this case. However, my guess is that

\begin{align}
& \operatorname{cov}\left(\int_0^tf(s,T_1)\,dW(s,T_1), \int_0^tf(s,T_2) \, dW(s,T_2)\right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_0^t f(s,T_1) f(s,T_2) c(s,T_1,T_2)\,ds.
\end{align}

However, I might be wrong but even if I am right I don't know how exactly to prove this.

Comment: I believe there should be $\int_0^t f(s,T_2) dW(s,T_2)$. Then your guess is correct.

Comment: For computing the covariance, $T_1,T_2$ are fixed and so you are really just in the Brownian motion case.

Comment: @zhoraster Yes, you are right, I corrected the typo.

Comment: @RhysSteele but it's a correlated BM right?

Comment: Of course, but that's not an issue? You essentially want to calculate the expectation of the covariation between the two Ito integrals and for that it's enough to know the covariation between your two BMs and you are in such a situation by assumption.